# How to extract base64 src from a video using just Javascript?

Tags: javascript

With we have a mp4 file how can we create a base64 src from it using just javascript?

For example, if he have a mp4 file named **example.mp4** located at **/assets/video/example.mp4**, how can extract the base64 data from it using Javascript to create a html tag like the example below?

```
<video id="video" width="740" controls>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,[VIDEO BASE64 DATA HERE]">
</video>
```

Instead of this:

```
<video id="video" width="740" controls>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="/assets/video/example.mp4">
</video>
```

The motivation to do this is because I need to transfer a encrypted file (for example a video, or a image, etc.) from one place to another. So I need using Javascript, extract the data, encrypt it and then transfer. How can we do this?

Comment: I wouldn't do that with JS... JS really isn't made to handle things like that.

Comment: What do you mean by encrypt/decrypt? Why can't the file just stay encrypted for the transferral?

Comment: The user will indicate the file, browsing it. The file will not be encrypted, it will be encrypted after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an answer, but I didn't tested yet: (MooTools)

http://jsfiddle.net/eliseosoto/JHQnk/

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label for="filePicker">Choose or drag a file:</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="filePicker">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <h1>Base64 encoded version</h1>
        <textarea id="base64textarea" placeholder="Base64 will appear here" cols="50" rows="15"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>



var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var file = files[0];

    if (files && file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
            var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
            document.getElementById("base64textarea").value = btoa(binaryString);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
};

if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('filePicker').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to adapt that code so that it is not necessary for a user to give a file?

This is, to be able to encode like you initially wanted, by knowing the location of the file and do that automatically, without intervention from the user.